# Pass argument in quotes with percent signs in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, hadoop, cmd, escaping, stat

I'm trying to use Hadoop's [`stat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat) command to retrieve file information from my HDFS. On Linux, you pass formatting strings to `stat` (similar to the GNU `stat` builtin) like:

```
$ hdfs dfs -stat "type:%F perm:%a %u:%g size:%b mtime:%y atime:%x name:%n" /file
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work in Windows' `cmd` prompt:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat "type:%F" /file

C:\> hdfs dfs -stat "type:%F" /
-stat: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: type:F
...
```

...it looks like it's trying to interpret the first argument as the path, instead of the second one. So I thought "maybe I need to include literal quotes?" Trying to escape the quotes with `^"` doesn't work:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat "^"type:%F^"" /
-stat: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ^^type:F
...
```

...in fact, it looks like it auto-escaped the `^` I sent in, but didn't send any quotes at all. Trying to surround the whole argument in single quotes rather than double quotes also doesn't work:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat '^"type:%F^"' /
-stat: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 'type:F'
...
```

This time, it included the single quotes but again skipped the double quotes. Double-escaping the carats also doesn't work:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat '^^"type:%F^^"' /
-stat: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 'type:F%5E%5E'
...
```

Triple-escaping the carats yields the same result as using a single carat.

I've found that a kludgey solution is to begin the formatting string with `%3`, and not surround it with quotes

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat %3%u /
3Andrew.Watsonuu

C:\> hdfs dfs -stat %3%u%g /
3Andrew.Watsonsupergroupgg
```

...but you can see that the returned string then has a `3` at the start, and the last flag character is doubled at the end `uu` or `gg`. I think this is because the `%N` are converted to the arguments that I passed to that function, like:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat %0 /
stat: `hadoop': No such file or directory
2019-09-25 12:28:00

C:\> hdfs dfs -stat %1 /
stat: `fs': No such file or directory
2019-09-25 12:28:00

C:\> hdfs dfs -stat "%2" /
-stat: Illegal option -stat
```

You can see that `%0`, `%1`, and `%2` correspond to the first, second, and third tokens in that command. So when I call %3, it substitutes the fourth argument into itself. This explains the weird repeated, glitchy output:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat %3"repeat" /
3repeat"repeat"repeat
```

**So the best solution I've come up with so far** is to pass a superfluous argument at the end (which will throw an error), but then reference that argument earlier in the command, like:

```
C:\> hdfs dfs -stat -R %6 / "%%u %%g %%Y" 2> nul
Andrew.Watson supergroup 1569414480510
Andrew.Watson supergroup 1568728730673
...
Andrew.Watson supergroup 1568103636381
Andrew.Watson supergroup 1568103590659
```

It throws that error at the end, which I hide by piping it to `nul`. There's got to be a better way to do this. Any ideas?